# How to optimize fine-tuned BERT's model size in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, text-classification, bert-language-model

After fine tuning BERT for classification the model size is ~1.3GB while the pre-trained model size was ~400MB. This happens due to additional variables related to Adam saved with the model and can be removed when saving, as explained in https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/99 for TensorFlow 1.x.

How to do this in TensorFlow 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. `save()` method of trained model has as an argument `include_optimizer` which is `True` by default. Setting it to `False` doesn't save optimizer's state and saved model file is comparable to the pre-trained file.